# Extracting data from nested json file using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I'm stuck with this issue. I've the below nested json.

```
{
  "current": {
    "timeSeries": [
      {
        "results": [
          {
            "count": 426
          }
        ],
        "beginTimeSeconds": 1490928320,
        "endTimeSeconds": 1490930120,
        "inspectedCount": 426
      },
      {
        "results": [
          {
            "count": 510
          }
        ],
        "beginTimeSeconds": 1490930120,
        "endTimeSeconds": 1490931920,
        "inspectedCount": 510
      }
    ]
  },
  "previous": {
    "timeSeries": [
      {
        "results": [
          {
            "count": 426
          }
        ],
        "beginTimeSeconds": 1490928320,
        "endTimeSeconds": 1490930120,
        "inspectedCount": 426
      },
      {
        "results": [
          {
            "count": 510
          }
        ],
        "beginTimeSeconds": 1490930120,
        "endTimeSeconds": 1490931920,
        "inspectedCount": 510
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to extract data from the above json and present it on webpage using google visualization api.

I've tried with below js and it didn't work.

```
function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/bay0v",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

   var options = {
      title : 'Sample json line chart',
      curveType : 'function',
    };

//var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
console.log(jsonData);
console.log(jsonData.current.timeSeries[0].beginTimeSeconds);

    var options = {
       hAxis: {
         title: 'Time',
         textStyle: {
           color: '#01579b',
           fontSize: 20,
           fontName: 'Arial',
           bold: true,
           italic: true
         },
         titleTextStyle: {
           color: '#01579b',
           fontSize: 16,
           fontName: 'Arial',
           bold: false,
           italic: true
         }
       },
       vAxis: {
         title: 'Popularity',
         textStyle: {
           color: '#1a237e',
           fontSize: 24,
           bold: true
         },
         titleTextStyle: {
           color: '#1a237e',
           fontSize: 24,
           bold: true
         }
       },
       colors: ['#a52714', '#097138']
     };

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 1400, height: 360});
}
```

I'm seeing below output in browser console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeSeries' of undefined
```

Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated. You'll need to write an (asynchronous) callback.

Comment: Thanks @trincot, but I don't have an issue reading jsonData object. When I print, it is printing whole json file. Do you have any suggestions to write an async callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `console.log` can be misleading because browsers tend to only look at the contents of the logged variable when you actually drill down in the nested structure that the console provides.

This means you can come under the false impression that that nested data was already there when the `console.log` call was made, which is not at all guaranteed.

Add to this that the `async: false` option has been deprecated, so that the Ajax call will most probably ignore this setting and run asynchronously.

So, rewrite your code to use a callback function that gets called when the response is available, for instance with `.done()`. Note also that jQuery offers the `$.getJSON` method as a shortcut for your Ajax call:

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/bay0v").done(function (jsonData) {
    console.log(jsonData.current.timeSeries[0].beginTimeSeconds);
    var options = {
        title : 'Sample json line chart',
        curveType : 'function',
    };
    // ...etc. Rest of your code comes here, or is called from here.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```